# time picker vue3 or input time

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am looking for a vue3 compatible timepicker, all the ones I have tried do not work with vue3. Is it possible to program a minimum time with an input time? for example: I want the user to only be able to select a +2 schedule. I explain, if for example it is 4:52 pm, I want it to be able to start selecting a time from 6:52 pm. Thank you for help

```
<template>
   <div>
     <input v-model="timeRetour" type="time" :min="timeCurrent()">
     <p>{{ timeRetour }}</p>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  date(){
    return{
      timeRetour:""
   }
 },
methods:{
  timeCurrent(){
            const current = new Date();
            console.log(current)
            const timeInstant = (current.getHours()+2) + ":" + current.getMinutes() 
            console.log(timeInstant)
            console.log(timeInstant)
            return timeInstant
        },
}
</script>
```

Comment: you need a computed property for that @tony

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Vishnu Bhadoriya, is it possible to put min which is in the input in reactive

Comment: yes it is, but remember validation only occurs when you submit form